# Is there a Python memoization library that supports version control?

Tags: python

I'm doing a data science project in Python. I need to cache results to reduce computation time.

In my code I'll use function `foo` to calculate `y = foo(x)` for different sets of parameters `x`. In addition to different parameters `x`, I an often modifying `foo` too. For example, I'll have one version of `foo` in git branch `branch-1` and another version of `foo` in git branch `branch-2`. I'll jump back-and-forth between these branches many times in a workday. I need a memoization library that caches the results of `branch-1` and `branch-2` separately iff `foo` has been called with different parameters or `foo`'s source code differs between `branch-1` and `branch-2`.

In other words, I need a library the following features.

- Computations are saved to the cache.
- Computations are not recomputed if they are in the cache.
- Computations *are* recomputed if they are not in the cache or the code generating them has been updated.
- Cache results are written to disk so they survive between different runs of my program.
- Cache results for outdated code are preserved in case I revert the code with git.

A few important points

- I'm okay with a system that detects whether the file containing `soo` has changed in place of detecting whether `soo`'s function definition has changed. But in that case "changed" has to depend solely on git commit history. It can't depend merely on unix timestamps because I use git and git does not preserve unix timestamps.
- I'm okay not using git history for versioning. It just seemed the most obvious approach to me.

**Does a library exist that to do this?**

I've already examined the following memoization libraries.

- `functools.lru_cache` and `python-memoization` don't work because neither of them write results to disk.
- Redis seems designed for web apps. Therefore I expect Redis is not designed to preserve caches for anything but the newest code.

Comment: I saw a workaround for your problem using cachetools and pickle here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962608/cachetools-for-subsequent-runs-in-python